# Running Access Macro whilst open using Batch file

Tags: ms-access, batch-file, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a batch file which contains a path to the access database. When clicked it opens up the desired database however I want the batch file to run the macro.

I can do this by creating a AutoExec macro to run when you open up the database but I also want the macro to run whilst the database is running.

Here is what I have on my batch file at the moment:

```
echo off
start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office\MSACCESS.EXE" "S:\DB NEW\Report.accdb"
```

How do I do this?

Comment: You mean by pressing a button on a form? Or?

Comment: No not from a button on form. I want the macro to run automatically whilst the database is running from .bat file

Comment: Then use a `Form_Timer`.

Comment: If you mean "at certain intervals", use the _timer event_ of a form, you keep open, to call the macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the /x "macroname" command line indicator to run a macro (not a VBA sub or function, a macro):

```
echo off
start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office\MSACCESS.EXE" "S:\DB NEW\Report.accdb" /x MyMacroName
```

Read more: [Command-line switches for office](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/command-line-switches-for-microsoft-office-products-079164cd-4ef5-4178-b235-441737deb3a6#ID0EAABAAA=Access).

Alternatively, you can read commands passed using the /cmd switch from VBA. You could use an auto-starting form that reads a command and executes a VBA function on load, or a predeclared class that reads and executes the command on initialize.

For more advanced functionality, I recommend switching to either PowerShell or VBScript. That way you can hook into running Access Application objects and get them to execute code.

Comment: Note that when when calling a macro from the command line, it seems that there's no way to prevent the *Autoexec* macro from running first.  Correct me if I'm wrong.